# Unable to use python-igraph, no method or attribute available after installation (Ubuntu 14.04.)

Tags: python, ubuntu, import, igraph

I installed python-igraph using synaptic on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. build-essential and python-dev are installed as well. But when I try to access anything within this library, nothing seems to work except importing the package. I'm using python 2.7.6.

First I try this:

```
import igraph
```

Output: nothing, so far so good.

With

```
import igraph
from igraph import *
```

I still get no output, so there should be nothing wrong.

For

```
import igraph
from igraph import *
dir(igraph)
```

I still get nothing, which is weird.

And if I start using igraph,

```
import igraph
from igraph import *
print igraph.__version__
```

this comes up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./igraph.py", line 1, in <module>
    import igraph
  File "/home/everdream/Downloads/igraph.py", line 3, in <module>
    print igraph.__version__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

Another example:

```
import igraph
from igraph import *
g = igraph.Graph.Tree(127, 2)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./igraph.py", line 1, in <module>
    import igraph
  File "/home/everdream/Downloads/igraph.py", line 3, in <module>
    g = igraph.Graph.Tree(127, 2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'
```

Can anyone advice me on what might be causing my problem? I don't even know where I should look for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You called your file `/home/everdream/Downloads/igraph.py`, rename it and remove the `igraph.pyc` file. You are trying to import from this file not the actual `igraph` module.

`import igraph;print igraph.__file__` will show you which file you have imported.

Comment: No worries, it is a simple mistake to make.